# Translate position from 3D camera to 2D camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I have 2 cameras, one for viewing the 3D objects (Perspective), and the other camera to view 2D objects (Orthographic).
(Also, the view of the camera never intercepts each other.)

I am trying to display a 2D object based on the position of a 3D object, like so:
[image: Image of what I am trying to achieve]

What I have is the respective 2D and 3D [`Camera`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html), as well as the `Vector3` position of the 3D `GameObject`.

*What I currently have:*

```
public Vector2 Convert3DPositionTo2DPosition(Camera camera3D, Vector3 position3D, Camera camera2D) {
    var tempPos = camera3D.WorldToViewportPoint(position3D);

    return camera2D.ViewportToWorldPoint(tempPos);
}
```

The only problem is that the returned position is not completely aligned with the 3D position.
Which results in this kind of results:
[image: Image of expected and actual result]

Also, I have made sure that both the 3D and 2D object have their pivot point are set correctly in the center, but it still does not work as intended.

(I am currently using `Unity 2019.1.14f1`)

#### Edit

TLDR of what I want:
I want a world position that is based on an object in view of the 3D camera which is now in view of the 2D camera and have them look like they are in the same position in the player's point of view (display screen).

What I am going to instantiate in afterwards (using that position) is a non-UI GameObject.
More specifically a particle system.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, but don't you just want `camera2D.WorldToViewportPoint` since you want to convert a world position into a 2D position?

Comment: @John I just tested it out, it did not work (same issue, but the actual position ended up being way further); Perhaps you could post the final code in case I missed out on something?

Comment: Hmm. I don't really do Unity so maybe I'm mistaken. It just seemed like you were converting a world position to a position in the camera's projection, and then converting that camera position to a 2D projection point.

Comment: @derHugo  I was using `ViewportToWorldPoint` and `ViewportToWorldPoint` since  I can get the relative position of the gameobject *relative to the 3D camera*, and then convert it to a world positive *relative to the 2D-camera*. `camera3D.WorldToScreenPoint(position3D)` wont cut it since it returns me a position based on the screen space, not based on the 2D camera; Converting it back to world-space with 2D camera using `ScreenToWorldPoint` is giving me the same issue too; I edited my question to make my goal clearer.

Comment: Do you maybe have an offset in the `Viewport Rect` of one of the cameras?

Comment: @derHugo It was the `Viewport Rect` values indeed, one of the value was unknowningly set as `1.1` rather than `1`; Thanks, the feature now works as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `Viewport Rect` settings for both of your `Camera`s!

[image]

if there is any difference between the two cameras you will always get an offset in the positions.

I tested your solution using

```
public Camera camera3d;
public Camera camera2d;
public Transform obj3d;
public Transform obj2d;

void Update()
{ 
    obj2d.position = camera2d.ViewportToWorldPoint(camera3d.WorldToViewportPoint(obj3d.position)); 
}
```

and it just works fine - as long as the `Viewport Rect` settings match - as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW7pN.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIhN2.jpg).